# User inputted list isn't converting strings to floats

Tags: python

It says `ValueError`, can't convert string to float. The user has to input a list of numbers, going up to three decimal places, but after I test it and enter the numbers, it doesn't work.

```
length = []
print("How long is each video in your channel?")

while True:
    
    length1 = float(input("Enter the length for each video:"))
                            
    length.append(length1)

print('The average time for all your videos is {:.3f}'.format(length))

print("The shortest video is:" (min(length)))

print("The longest video is:" (max(length)))
```

Comment: What  numbers did you try to input?  How did you try to end the list?  This is a data problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: You don't have any way to terminate the loop other than crashing the program by putting in a value that can't be converted to float.

Comment: You're also missing syntax in the last 2 print statements

Comment: You need to have a termination condition to break from loop and the average should be calculated by taking the sum of array and dividing by len(length) where length is your array of floats.

Comment: put two argument in like this print('The average time for all your videos is {:.3f}'.format(length)) but you will not get exact output you should also use math to divide and multiply to get average and mix max length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't have a way to end the loop.  You were missing commas in the last two statements.  When you tried to print the average, you just passed the whole list.  That doesn't work; you need to compute the average.  This works; just press "enter" to end the loop:

```
length = []
print("How long is each video in your channel?")
while True:
    length1 = input("Enter the length for each video:")
    if not length1:
        break
    length.append(float(length1))

avg = sum(length)/len(length)
print('The average time for all your videos is {:.3f}'.format(avg))
print("The shortest video is:", (min(length)))
print("The longest video is:", (max(length)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There were few logical and syntactical runtime errors, I debugged them,

This is for you,

```
    length = []
    n = int(input("Enter the no.of videos : "))
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        print("Enter the length of video ", i + 1, ':')
        length1 = float(input())
        length.append(length1)
        i+=1
    print('The average time of all your videos is 
    {:.3f}'.format(sum(length)/len(length)))
    print("The shortest video is:", (min(length)))
    print("The longest video is:", (max(length)))
```

To make the loop finite, I used the counter variable ***'i'***

Corrected the logic for average calculation & brought the missing commas back into the last 2 print statements

I hope this one will clear your doubts :)

Comment: You can use `len(length)+1` and skip the `i` counter...